# OkHttp with TTL

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I use OkHttp to get some data from backend on the app start. The request performed just once. Response string is parsed to the data class, stored in memory and used during the app lifetime. Now backend asked me to cache some data with TTL.

```
if some_key in cache: return cache.get(some_key)
else:
    get value, ttl from BE.
    populate cache with ttl
    return value
```

What is the fastest way to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While creating your `OkHttpClient` instance just apply `.cache` method to builder like this:

```
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .cache(Cache(context.getCacheDir(), cacheSize)
    .build()
```

Edit:

To repeat the request after the body has expired you must first get the max-age value from request:

```
val cacheControl = CacheControl.parse(data.headers())
val maxAge = cacheControl.maxAgeSeconds()
```

And then schedule the next request with something like JobScheduler or AlarmManager or if you're sure the current thread won't get killed before the next request you can just post a delayed runnable:

```
Handler().postDelayed({
    // make request
}, cacheControl.maxAgeSeconds().toLong().times(1000))
```

Comment: Thanks. But how it's related to TTL? I see only cache size here.

Comment: OkHttp honors your server's cache headers. They should add a Cache-Contol header.

Comment: Ok. But this request is made only once, on the app start. Is there any mechanism to repeat this request when TTL is done?